# How can I disable incoming videos in Zoom on Windows as a meeting guest (not host/admin)?

Tags: video, zoom-meeting

I found the option to disable incoming video in Zoom on iPadOS but not Windows:

[image]

How can I disable incoming videos in Zoom on Windows?

Note: I'm not the meeting admin/host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article
[Stopping all incoming video in a meeting or webinar](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/4409500570381-Stopping-all-incoming-video-in-a-meeting-or-webinar):

> To enable or disable Enable "stop incoming video" feature for your own
> use:
>
> 1. Sign in to the Zoom web portal.
> 2. In the navigation panel, click Settings.
> 3. Click the **Meeting** tab.
> 4. Under **In-meeting (Advanced)**, click the **Enable "stop incoming video" feature** toggle to enable or disable it.
> 5. If a verification dialog displays, click **Enable** or **Disable** to verify the change.
>    **Note**: If the option is grayed out, it has been
>    locked at either the group or account level. You need to contact your
>    Zoom admin.

Per the above Note, if having done the described actions and you
still cannot access this option, then it must have been disabled,
and you should contact your Zoom administrator and ask for it
to be enabled.

The post
[Stop incoming video](https://community.zoom.com/t5/Meetings/Stop-incoming-video/m-p/12953#M5882)
has this important message:

> All backend issues with Stop incoming video have been resolved, so this should be available for all now. Be sure to enable it in web settings, as well as in-client settings. Once those are both enabled, you should have the in-meeting option.

So check if the option is enabled in the web login.

Comment: Thanks, is "click the "stop incoming video" feature" a parameter for the host or a regular meeting participant? I do see it in a meeting I participate in, but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: Ask the meeting administrator, or site administrator, if it's intentionally disabled.

Comment: Zoom on iPad does allow me to disable incoming videos in the same meeting, so I'm guessing it's not disabled. Unless the restriction only applies to Microsoft Windows?

Comment: Perhaps. Are you using the same Zoom version on both?

Comment: both OSes use the latest Zoom version + same Zoom account.

Comment: It's possible that the Windows adaptation of Zoom is lacking features that are available in OSX. I added more info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I disable incoming videos in Zoom on Windows as a meeting guest (not host/admin)?

`View` (top right corner) -> `Stop Incoming Video`:

[image]